# POSTMAN PUT request not updating values

Tags: javascript, api, postman, multipartform-data, imgur

Assuming the position of the API tester of https://imgur.com/ , Im testing the PUT request to change account settings.
I am following this api doc
[image]
Link for above https://apidocs.imgur.com/#7bc88d39-d06d-4661-afff-38ea5b9a1d0a

Steps to check this

1. Add the relevant info as below, I am setting show_mature and newsletter_subscribed to true

[image]
2. Set the Access token
[image]
3. Click on send
the response for this is 200 as shown below
[image]

4. Check if the details have updated as shown in the following screenshot
   [image]

**Expected**: To have show_mature and newsletter_subscribed values set to true
**Actual**: show_mature and newsletter_subscribed values are false

Would be really appreciated if someone could let me know why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: Some APIs are poorly documented and actually want `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data and not `multipart/form-data`. Try using the `x-www-form-urlencoded` option instead of `form-data`

Comment: can toggle all the properties by changing to /x-www-form-urlencoded now, however the property newsletter_subscribed wont toggle -any possible causes? - thanks

Comment: No idea. Make sure you have no whitespace characters in your keys or values. Otherwise, contact Imgur support and while you're there, let them know their documentation is bad

Comment: sure, thanks:) will give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Imgur API docs](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#intro)...

> ### Need help?
>
> The Imgur engineers are always around answering questions. The quickest way to get help is by posting your question on StackOverflow with the [Imgur tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imgur).

Real helpful Imgur .

Answering here to provide a canonical answer in the [imgur](/questions/tagged/imgur) tag for this nonsense.

All the API examples in the documentation use some form of `multipart/form-data` request body payloads. Eg

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer {{accessToken}}");

var formdata = new FormData();

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://api.imgur.com/3/account/{{username}}/settings", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

and

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token' \
--form 'refresh_token="{{refreshToken}}"' \
--form 'client_id="{{clientId}}"' \
--form 'client_secret="{{clientSecret}}"' \
--form 'grant_type="refresh_token"'
```

With the exception of any *upload* related endpoints, this is **ABSOLUTELY INCORRECT**. Passing data as `multipart/form-data` requires the API to handle that request content-type and guess what, the Imgur API **does not**.

What they do accept is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

- In Postman that's the `x-www-form-urlencoded` option, not `form-data`
- In cURL that's the `-d` option, not `--form`
- In JavaScript that's [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), not [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: Really appreciated PHIl